# Dropping hive partition based on certain condition in runtime

Tags: shell, hive

I have a table in hive built using the following command:

`create table t1 (x int, y int, s string) partitioned by (wk int) stored as sequencefile;`

The table has the data below:

```
select * from t1;
+-------+-------+-------+--------+--+
| t1.x  | t1.y  | t1.s  | t1.wk  |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+--+
| 1     | 2     | abc   | 10     |
| 4     | 5     | xyz   | 11     |
| 7     | 8     | pqr   | 12     |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+--+
```

Now the ask is to drop the oldest partition when partition count is `>=2`
Can this be handled in hql or through any shell script and how?

Considering I will be using dbname as variable like `hive -e 'use "$dbname"; show partitions t1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your partitions are ordered by date, you could write a shell script in which you could use [`hive -e 'SHOW PARTITIONS t1'`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowTables/Views/Partitions/Indexes) to get all partitions, in your example, it will return:

```
wk=10
wk=11
wk=12
```

Then you can issue [`hive -e 'ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION (wk=10)'`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-DropPartitions) to remove the first partition;

So something like:

```
db=mydb
if (( `hive -e "use $db; SHOW PARTITIONS t1" | grep wk | wc -l` < 2)) ; then
    exit;
fi
partition=`hive -e "use $db; SHOW PARTITIONS t1" | grep wk | head -1`;
hive -e "use $db; ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION ($partition)";
```

Comment: yes it will be ordered by week_key. But how show partitions help? Can you provide sample commands

Comment: @KoushikChandra I added some code which I haven't run. If it's helpful, feel free to propose an edit to this answer if some changes are required for it to work...

Comment: If I want to use a database name in a variable then the same command is not working like hive -e 'show partitions $dbname.t1' > /home/$USER/t1.txt

Comment: no it didn't work .. FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 cannot recognize input near '$' 'dbname' '<EOF>' in switch database statement

Comment: In fact can't recognize $ in the statement hive -e 'ALTER TABLE t1 DROP PARTITION ($partition)'

Comment: You're correct - I fixed my answer - you should use double quotes (")