# History maintain in hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive

How can we purge data that is older than 4 months hadoop? The data is partitioned based on mkt and month

---

Suppose we have data in partition table like

```
/user/test/mkt=1/month=200001
/user/test/mkt=1/month=200002
/user/test/mkt=1/month=200005
```

As an example, when we get the data for month of 200006 we need to purge the first record i.e. `/user/test/mkt=1/month=200001`; when we get 200007 we need to delete 200002 data.

In this way we can maintain 5 months data at any point.

Comment: What attempts have you made? Are you looking to have the system move the data out so hive can't read it any longer or delete the data permanently?

Comment: Please refer to the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454420/dropping-hive-partition-based-on-certain-condition-in-runtime). It may help to solve your problem.